# Are there rules or certain trigo angles that are easier to remember or is there a way to find the angle?

Tags: trigonometry

> For example $\sin x =\frac{1}{2}$, find the angle $x$ = $\frac{\pi}{6}$

I understand that using a right-angle triangle, the ratio is $1:2$ for a sine function. but how do I evaluate the value of the angle without a calculator?

Comment: [Sines and cosines of special angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_in_trigonometry#Sines_and_cosines_of_special_angles)

Comment: There was a similar question posted recently, take a look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523058/how-to-find-the-measure-of-an-angle-in-degrees-radians-from-inverse-trigonometri?noredirect=1#comment9502354_4523058

Answer (score 0):

Only a few values of any trigonometric functions correspond to "nice" angles (meaning in general, a whole number of degrees or a suitable rational number tines $\pi$ radians). So if you are given a number *a priori* to find its inverse sine or cosine, chances are there is no compact expression other than $\sin^{-1}$or $\cos^{-1}$ of the number. For instance, the only rational numbers whose square roots have a "nice" inverse sine or cosine are $0,\pm1/4,\pm1/2,\pm3/4,\pm1$. You won't get an elegant inverse cosine of $\sqrt{1/3}$, for example.

Of course, an example may be "rigged" to give a nice angle; if so, then there are ways to reduce the equation to something from which a rational multiple of $\pi$ radians or whole number of degrees can be read off by inspection. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4512850/248217) for a couple such cases.